# ui router issue with Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, materialize

I am using [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/) with Angular `ui.router` to handle states and render HTML.

But facing issue with Materialize Select as it is not initialized on state change as Materialize components renders on document load.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row no-gutter margin-bottom-0">
    <div class="input-field col s4">
        <label>Date</label>
        <select ng-model="day" ng-options="o for o in days" required>
            <option value="DD">DD</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        templateUrl: '/partials/signup.html',
        onEnter: function($window){$window.document.title = "SignUp"; }
    })
```

I tried using resolve as below:

```
resolve: {
       function(){
         $('select').material_select();
        }
 },
```

but no luck.. Any idea how to reinitialize material_select();

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Angular does not work as intended with Materialize, try incorporating Angular Materialize: http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#select

Comment: I did that but facing errors in directives declared in angular materialize.